# Docker container: kill command not found

Tags: linux, docker

Noob question here: I'm using a docker image based on docker-slim, which doesn't seem to have the `kill` command by default. I tried using `apt-get install kill`, but apt can't find the package.

What should I install to have this command at my disposal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kill command is in package procps. So `apt-get install procps` will do.